# How to resolve VScode terminal lag / choppiness when typing?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Not sure if this is from Big Sur, installing the Docker extension or what else it could be but in the last week, I have noticed that when typing in the VScode terminal, every single time that I've done my git add. , git commit -m "etc", git push origin master, there is always once or twice where the terminal visually shows that I'm not typing anything for a brief moment. It essentially lags and shows the typing white square icon and in 1 second after a brief "pause" what I was actually typing appears as normal. This happens intermittently and even after removing the Docker addon and making my VScode settings as:

`"terminal.integrated.allowChords": false,   "terminal.integrated.drawBoldTextInBrightColors": false,   "terminal.integrated.experimentalLinkProvider": false, "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "auto"`

I still notice that there is this random 1 second pausing and choppiness when typing that happens. Is there a solution to this? I did not experience this for the full past year that I used this MBP 2019 16inch and it only just recently started.

Answer (score 7):

See this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105446

As reported there, running

`codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code\ Helper\ \(Renderer\).app`

in the terminal and then reloading vscode seems to fix the issue for many people.

Comment: what exactly does this command do? I want to run it and give it a shot but i'd rather know what it does first exactly and if the root issue with vscode or the vscode terminal is identifiable as to why this lag issue is occurring.

Comment: There is quite a bit of discussion at the linked issue.

Comment: Indeed and it was closed after the users reported that the stated command solved their problem. Mine too....   ;-)

Comment: I still cannot determine what this command does but I am seeing that it may not necessarily work anymore. Do either of you know if VScode or Apple knows this issue and has a fix in the works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your settings.json:

`"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "canvas"`

If that doesn't help then try:

`"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off"`