# How to fix VS Code integrated terminal choppy and laggy on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

Typing in the integrated terminal in VS Code on Big Sur is very annoyingly laggy and slow. This is the only application that experiences this, iTerm, etc. do not experience this issue. I tried disabling all plug-ins, themes, fonts, etc. to try to get to root cause.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/65064954/836330

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the thread [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105446) I was able to successfully mitigate the issue by running this command: `codesign --remove-signature /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code\ Helper\ \(Renderer\).app` and restarting VS Code, the lag is completely gone and everything is back to normal.

If you trust VS Code developer then removing the signature should *not* be an issue but YMMV.

For me, I was super happy to find this solution, as it was driving me crazy.

Comment: Any cost by removing the signature? Is it possible to undo when the bug fixed?

Comment: @ktutnik I believe when you install a newer version of VS Code, you can remove the application completely and then install the new version and it should be back to having a signature again. I haven't confirmed this though.

Comment: Didn't help in my case. I get the sluggish terminal only in VS Code Remote. Anyone else with that issue?

Comment: @Casimir I think you can start a new question with that, which would be "How to mitigate VS Code Remote sluggishness?"

Answer (score 13):

Probably an update on Konstantin Popovskikh's answer that was deleted.

In settings.json, setting this:

```
  "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off",
```

Helped a lot for me, however it does have the side effect of not rendering underscores while typing - but for me, this is the lesser of two evils.

**Note**: You don't appear to have to reload the session you can just save the .json file and the terminal will update (you can visibly see it change slightly).

Comment: Yeah for me, I never want to not use the gpu or have rendering degradation. But this is useful to know, especially on gpu constrained machines where you dont need this feature on anyway.

Comment: This seems to be working beautifully for me...VSCode tells me that it should be slower the other way around. Any insight into why this works? Also, the terminal is text, how could a GPU accelerate it in the first place?

Comment: @tslater - that is a good question I am also surprised that this is a feature for a terminal. My best guess is for rendering high-quality / graphical fonts - so they look and scroll perfectly.

Comment: For me, it made the terminal even slower!

Comment: Setting it to "on" helped me. Thanks for the hint